# Python continuous writing failed

Tags: python

I want to read and write files multiple times.But the way is failed,it only writes the last modified content rather than all modified contents.

The incorrect program

```
def openfile():
    txt = open("test.txt", "r")
    contents = txt.readlines()
    txt.close()
    return contents

def write_file(contents,f):
    old_contents = openfile()
    old_contents.insert(1,contents)
    contents = "".join(old_contents )
    f.write(contents)
    f.close()

text1 = open("test.txt","w")
contents= "test1 \n"
write_file(contents,text1)

text2 = open("test.txt","w")
contents = "test2 \n"
write_file(contents,text2)**
```

Worry Output

```
test2
```

My hope output

```
test1
test2
```

Comment: I don't understand, you posted the answer in the question?

Comment: try to use "a" flag instead of 'w'

Comment: I just want to know why the first way is worry

Comment: Only open and close the file once.

Comment: @K.Suthagar Opening the file in append mode is certainly the right way to perform this operation. However, the OP is asking why their current approach isn't working, so I won't close this question as a duplicate of the one you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too much of code for the File Open and Write, You can just use this following lines to append the text in your file

```
def FileSave(filename,content):
    with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(content)

FileSave("test.txt","test1 \n")
FileSave("test.txt","test2 \n")
```

Here, when we using this line `open(filename, "a")`, the `a` indicates the appending the file, that means allow to insert extra data to the existing file

Answer (score 1):

as stated in the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) you need to open your file with `mode='a'` if you want to append to existing data; `mode='w'` simply overwrites:

```
with open(file='_test.txt', mode='a') as file:
    file.write('test')
```

(if you are using python 2, change the variable name `file` above to something else; in python 2 `file` is a keyword).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your "Worry Output" is that you re-open "test.txt" in read mode inside `openfile` after you've already opened it in write mode outside the functions. When you open a file in write mode it gets truncated, i.e., the file pointer is positioned to the start of the file and the current contents of the file are discarded. So when you call `openfile` inside `write_file` the file is empty, and thus `openfile` returns an empty list.

Here's a repaired version of your code. We use `try... except` in `openfile` so we can return an empty list if the file doesn't exist.

```
def openfile(fname):
    try:
        f = open(fname, "r")
        contents = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return contents
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []

def write_file(contents, fname):
    old_contents = openfile(fname)
    old_contents.insert(1,contents)
    contents = "".join(old_contents)
    f = open(fname, "w")
    f.write(contents)
    f.close()

contents= "test1 \n"
write_file(contents, "test.txt")

contents = "test2 \n"
write_file(contents, "test.txt")
```

And here are the contents of "test.txt" after running that code:

```
test1 
test2
```

Actually, it's better to use `with` when opening files:

```
def openfile(fname):
    try:
        with open(fname, "r") as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
        return contents
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []

def write_file(contents, fname):
    old_contents = openfile(fname)
    old_contents.insert(1,contents)
    contents = "".join(old_contents)
    with open(fname, "w") as f:
        f.write(contents)
```

---

However, a much better way to do this is to simply open the file in append mode as hiro protagonist and K.Suthagar have already shown. But I figured it was a good idea to explain why your current code didn't do what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 1):

`text1 = open("test.txt","w")`

It is because above code resets the content. "w" is to override the file content.

Below code should explain you where you went wrong-

```
def openfile():
    txt = open("test.txt", "r")
    contents = txt.readlines()
    print "Openfile method- Contents: "+str(contents)
    txt.close()
    return contents

def write_file(contents,f):
    print "WriteFile method- Content received: "+str(contents)
    old_contents = openfile()
    print "Writefile method- Old content read from file: "+str(old_contents)
    old_contents.insert(1,contents)
    print "Writefile method- Old content after insertion: "+str(old_contents)
    contents = "".join(old_contents )
    print "WriteFile method- Content to write: "+str(contents)
    f.write(contents)
    f.close()

text1 = open("test.txt","w")
contents= "test1 \n"
write_file(contents,text1)

text2 = open("test.txt","w")
contents = "test2 \n"
write_file(contents,text2)
```

As mentioned, use "a" to append to file.